# How to center the page title in ConstraintLayout

Tags: android, android-activity, android-constraintlayout

I am using ConstraintLayout to show the page, and I can't find the way to make the title at center of the bar. I didn't use the action bar or tools bar. The solution I found online is all about add a label on active bar which I don't have.

Here is the layout:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="right"
    tools:context="com.spydertrap.occexample.MainActivity"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp"
    tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="0dp">

    <android.support.constraint.Guideline
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/guideline2"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.5"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="0dp"
        tools:layout_editor_absoluteX="206dp" />


    <android.support.v7.widget.CardView
        android:id="@+id/cardView2"
        android:layout_height="150dp"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline2"
        android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/cardView"
        android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="8dp">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"
            android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/resource" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/textView3"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginTop="116dp"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
            android:textAppearance="@style/CardSubTitle"
            android:text="Resource Center" />
    </android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

and the activity is pretty simple:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        setTitle("Dashboard");
    }
}
```

[This title needs to be centered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vcBXz.png)

any help will be appreciated!!

Comment: you are saying that u are not using action bar or toolbar then how u setting that here not see it in your layout?

Comment: I didn't set it in my layout. I only set the title content in the activity.

Comment: then it is action bar you are using action bar theme

Comment: Pavan, thank you. I just notice that there is a action bar although it doesn't show in my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Override the setTitle(CharSequence title) method of the Activity.

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    setTitle("Dashboard");

}

@Override
public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
    super.setTitle(title);

    TextView textView = new TextView(this);
    textView.setText(title);
    textView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
    textView.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL);
    getSupportActionBar().setDisplayOptions(ActionBar.DISPLAY_SHOW_CUSTOM);
    getSupportActionBar().setCustomView(textView);
}
```